# Bootstrap grid issues

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, containers, grid-system

I'm new to the whole bootstrap grid system.

For some reasons, I can't get rid of the horizontal scroll bar that suddenly appeared that makes my content move right and left.

Even if I remove the container it's still present. 
I have tried many different ways but nothing works. I hope I could find some help here.

Here is my HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="col-lg-4 navbar-brand">BySofie</a>
        </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class="col-lg-5 nav navbar-right navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a>START</a></li>
            <li><a>OM MIG</a></li>
            <li><a>KOMPETENCER</a></li>
            <li><a>PORTFOLIO</a></li>
            <li><a>KONTAKT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav> <!--end navbar-->

<section class="container-fluid">    <!--main section-->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
       <img class="img-responsive" src="images/background_flower.png"/>
    </div>        
</div>
</section>               <!--end main section-->
```

Comment: What version of bootstrap? I can't see any scrollbar on [this](https://codepen.io/fen1x/pen/wqPBOB?editors=1000) codepen

Comment: Can't find the issue, Please check https://jsbin.com/serovip

Comment: That is so weird. Im using Bootstrap 3.3.7

Comment: I added my css https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZJaGWa?editors=1100 and now the scrollbar appeared.

Comment: what browser do you use? no scrollbar for me in FF 54 and none in chrome 60

Comment: Google Chrome. I think I found the problem then. I removed:     
 .container . .container-fluid {
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
}   but as soon I put a row into my div in the section the scrollbar appears

Comment: It is resolved. Thanks for the help :-) "row" and the image didnt work well together, so I added "row-fluid" instead of just "row"